# Label text not changing instantly on python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, time

in this script the label text only changes after 2 seconds. is it possible to change label text instantly? i need `time.sleep(2)` since i am using `python-vlc` and i want to change the label text before playing the audio.

```
import tkinter
import time

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.testLabel = tkinter.Label(self.root, text = 'I am suhail')
        self.changetextBtn = tkinter.Button(self.root,text="change txt", command=self.chngbtn)
        self.testLabel.pack()
        self.changetextBtn.pack()
        self.n_clicks = 0

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def chngbtn(self):
        self.testLabel["text"] = f'Changed text: {self.n_clicks} times'
        self.n_clicks+=1
        time.sleep(2)

myGUI = MyGUI()
```

you can see the code of what i am trying at https://github.com/suhailvs/pyqurantorah/blob/bbe0dfa81a9248e1932f746b3b5fcf4548fc58f9/forms/quran.py#L100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self.root.update()` or `self.root.update_idletasks()` to refresh it, immediately after changing label.

```
def chngbtn(self):
    self.testLabel["text"] = f'Changed text: {self.n_clicks} times'
    self.root.update() # or self.root.update_idletasks()
    self.n_clicks+=1
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: exactly what i need. thank you very much. i have been stuck on this for few hours and nearly giveup.. :)